# why use sessions in a wcf chat application

Tags: wcf, session

i came across an example of a wcf client - server chat app.

[chat app](http://islameldemery.blogspot.com/2008/05/wcf-serverclient-chat-sample.html)

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(ISampleChatCallback), SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ISampleChat
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true, IsOneWay=true)]
    void Connect(string name);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SayToServer(string name, string msg);

    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = true, IsOneWay = true)]
    void Disconnect(string name);
}
```

i am trying to understand why would i require a session in a chat app ? ( what important role does it perform on the server)

Answer (score 0):

What transport binding was being used in the sample? My experience with callback contracts is that certain bindings require sessions and some do not.

For example netTcpBinding does not require sessions but wsDualHttpBinding does.

Comment: So you don't require sessions then

Comment: i read in O'Reillys Learning WCF 
when using nettcpbinding the defaults are  SessionMode.Allowed 
and the InstanceContextMode.PerSession 
so when working with nettcpbindings it works with seasons 
and if we where to communicate(different binding) some other way it would communicate 
on a perCall bases .

Comment: from the above code it seems it is based on duplex connection. does duplex connection http binding...i think not. so user has to go for tcp/ip binding......am i right?